# javaScript function for showing and hiding html divs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, function

I confess I have not done javaScript or html for 20 years, and I have forgotten lots.  What's wrong with this html page?  It displays a button and two div blocks.  On the first click, both divs should disappear.  The first div should appear on the next click.  Both divs should appear on the third click.  Subsequent clicks should repeat the cycle.  Nothing happens when I click the button.

```js
function myFunction(namesDiv, valuesDiv) {

  var nD = document.getElementById(namesDiv);
  var vD = document.getElementById(valuesDiv);
  if (vD.style.display ==== "none") {
    vD.style.display ==== "block";
    nD.style.display ==== "none";
  } else if (nD.style.display ==== "none") {
    nD.style.display ==== "block";
  } else {
    nD.style.display ==== "none";
    vD.style.display ==== "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<button onclick="myFunction(\"divID0.955919\",\"divID0.956012\")"> Report Outline</button>
<div id="divID0.956012">
  <p>Image goes here</p>
  <p>Comment goes here</p>
</div>
<div id="divID0.955919">
  <ul>
    <li>Bull Pucky1 </li>
    <li>Bull Pucky2 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: `====` is not a valid JavaScript operator. Use `===` or `==` for comparison and `=` for assignment

Comment: _"I have forgotten lots"_  check out the Mozilla Developer Network. Probably the best collection of documentation and guides you can find ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript

Comment: you also set the stle wrong for the elements. I added an working answere. Check it out.

Comment: @MrMaavin it's the assignment operator that is wrong, not the use of `style.display`

Comment: Another hint for debugging... open your browser's JavaScript console so you can see the errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

In JavaScript `====` is not a valid operator.

For comparison you have to use `===` (for both *value* and *type* check) or `==` (for only *value* check) and for assignment you have to use `=`.

You also have some syntax error in

```
<button onclick="myFunction(\"divID0.955919\",\"divID0.956012\")"> Report Outline</button>
```

Change that to

```
<button onclick="myFunction('divID.0955919','divID.0956012')"> Report Outline</button>
```

```js
function myFunction(namesDiv,valuesDiv){
  var nD = document.getElementById(namesDiv);
  var vD = document.getElementById(valuesDiv);

  if (vD.style.display === "none")
  {
      vD.style.display = "block";
      nD.style.display = "none";
  }
  else if (nD.style.display === "none")
  {
      nD.style.display = "block";
  }
  else
  {
      nD.style.display = "none";
      vD.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <title>Page Title</title> </head>
<body> 
    <button onclick="myFunction('divID.0955919','divID.0956012')"> Report Outline</button>
    <div id="divID.0956012">
        <p>Image goes here</p>
        <p>Comment goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="divID.0955919">
        <ul>
            <li>Bull Pucky1 </li>
            <li>Bull Pucky2 </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

As `====` is not a valid operator in javascript

Your function should be

```
function myFunction(namesDiv, valuesDiv) {

  var nD = document.getElementById(namesDiv);
  var vD = document.getElementById(valuesDiv);
  if (vD.style.display == "none") {
    vD.style.display = "block";
    nD.style.display = "none";
  } else if (nD.style.display == "none") {
    nD.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    nD.style.display = "none";
    vD.style.display = "none";
  }
 }
```

and this should be your html

```
<button onclick="myFunction('divID0.955919','divID0.956012')"> Report Outline</button>
<div id="divID0.956012">
    <p>Image goes here</p>
    <p>Comment goes here</p>
</div>
<div id="divID0.955919">
    <ul>
        <li>Bull Pucky1 </li>
        <li>Bull Pucky2 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Have a look at [javascript operators](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp) for detailed information

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the correct script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <title>Page Title</title> </head>
<body> <script>

        function myFunction(namesDiv,valuesDiv)
        {
            var nD = document.getElementById(namesDiv);
            var vD = document.getElementById(valuesDiv);
            if (vD.style.display === "none")
            {
                vD.style.display = "block";
                nD.style.display = "none";
            }
            else if (nD.style.display === "none")
            {
                nD.style.display = "block";
            }
            else
            {
                nD.style.display = "none";
                vD.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="myFunction('divID0.955919','divID0.956012')"> Report Outline</button>
    <div id="divID0.956012">
        <p>Image goes here</p>
        <p>Comment goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="divID0.955919">
        <ul>
            <li>Bull Pucky1 </li>
            <li>Bull Pucky2 </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>`enter code here`
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some explanation to your answer.